# Guide for recognizing objects in an image scene

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition, object-recognition

I spent days to search about this topic and I found some good articles, but all them discuss about theory, and I have to implement it using MATLAB. Specified object are picked from Caltec 101 dataset. I know to reach this goal there are many methods, using objects geometric features, template matching, and other methods. Is there any tutorial to implement one of this methods in MATLAB?

*I can choose another dataset, it's not forced to use Caltec 101

Caltec 101:[image: Caltec 101:] 


Another dataset
[image: Another dataset]

Comment: This questions need to be much more specific.

Comment: It's pretty clear, I want to recognize specific objects in a given scene

Comment: I agree with kigurai, because you didn't say anything about the method you want, your question is too generic

Comment: OK, I want to use objects geometric properties.

Comment: Then edit your question and say so. The question is still very vague on the requirements regarding what objects are to be found, the background, occlusion, scale variations, and a heap of other stuff that would be good to know. A clear written question with examples are always a good way to get better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that works almost directly "off-the-shelf" and that is mostly coded in MATLAB, you should try the framework developed for "[Discriminatively Trained Deformable Part Models](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/papers/latent.pdf)" and subsequent papers in  [PAMI 2010](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/papers/lsvm-pami.pdf) and [CVPR 10](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/papers/cascade.pdf). You can find all the code for this framework [on a site](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/latent/) hosted by the authors.

Even though the title of the first paper may suggest that the system is designed to deal  with objects with deformable parts only, the system works on a wide variety of object categories, rigid or with deformable parts.

This system also won the [Lifetime Achievement Prize](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/voc2010/workshop/) from the PASCAL Visual Object Classes Challenge Workshop 2010, in recognition for (I quote):

> "First submitted to the PASCAL VOC challenge in 2007, this detector
>   has now become a core component of many classification, segmentation,
>   person layout and action classification submissions. We honour the
>   contribution made to the community by the innovation and success of
>   the method and its free distribution."